# how to change this code

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date,  
  A.Model,  
  COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Qty,  
  B.Name  
FROM inspection_report AS A  
LEFT JOIN Employee AS B ON A.NIK = B.NIK  
 GROUP BY A.Model, A.Serial_number
```

Comment: A question usually requires a question ;-)

Comment: Change to do what? Or is there something wrong with it? You might need more columns on the `GROUP BY` to match the list you're returning (e.g. `DATE(A.Inspection_datetime)`), and it'd make more sense to `COUNT()` on a column in table B rather than the column you're grouping on (e.g. B.NIK) though that might not actually be a problem.

Comment: Click on the parts of the code you want changed with your mouse which will probably be located somewhere near your computer. You will need to then press the corresponding keys on your character entry device to apply the changes in the code. Feel free to use both hands, you don't need to keep hold of the mouse when you are happy with the pointers position on your monitor.

Comment: Finally a question that really deserves the "not a real question" closing.

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would be nice too.

Answer (score 6):

At a guess (and believe me, I'm guessing)

```
SELECT DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date,   
  A.Model,   
  COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Qty,   
  B.Name   
FROM inspection_report AS A   
LEFT JOIN Employee AS B ON A.NIK = B.NIK   
 GROUP BY A.Model, B.Name
```

You need to group by the fields you're not aggregating

Comment: For bonus points, change the alias for Employee from `B` to `Beat`, then you can have a `Beat.Nik` :)

Comment: For mega bonus points, then change nik to root, then you will have a beat.root which is a tasty and healthy vegetable whose promotion can only better the world.